# How to get more specific with a PIP question, without leading the question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I've [asked this question on the PIP](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/83986/2762) (performance improvement process).  Before I added more details, the question received a few flags.

One way to interpret most of the answers is that "anxiety is natural to performance discussions, so the question is unanswerable."

If we consider that we can always do better, then saying "don't try" or "just be a good manager" is not getting at the root of the matter.  (in that case, maybe it is a dupe?)

But the reasons for flagging may not be that simple.

How might a question like this be improved further?  I would like to make it a durable Q&A exchange on the PIP topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your questions is currently closed for being unclear. However, I think while not perfect, it's fairly clear what you are asking so I have voted to reopen.

That being said, I don't think you're going to get any answers better than enderland's and Dan Pichelman's. A PIP tells an employee that their job is at risk if they do not improve, and knowing that you might be fired soon is inherently stressful. There's not much you can do about it except for the few things already laid out in the posted answers.

Comment: Actually the 2nd edit clarified it enough for me I have voted to reopen as well.

Comment: What you can do about it is *manage the employee for Improvement* rather than jumping to the nuclear option of a PIP. There is no way to make putting someone on a PIP anything but a severe repremand and threat of firing for cause. If that is not what you intended, you had no business invoking the PIP process.

Comment: @keshlam Yes, I think the first half of [Dan's answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/83989/16983) covers that. "That's your informal low stress Performance Improvement Plan. It's low stress because you're just doing your job and you're not explicitly mentioning consequences for noncompliance."